# Give examples of proofs of program correctness using induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am teaching discrete math for computer science majors and I want some good examples of how mathematical induction is used to prove program correctness.

I have lots of experience with math induction but no experience with proofs of correctness so a few simple then harder examples would be nice.

Also, if you know any resources (books or papers) that talk about this that would be great.

Comment: Guys on [another site](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [rather this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) may have more idea.

Comment: @Freddy, real programmers do no stinkin' proofs... Look for the books by Gries "A science of programming" or so. Dijkstra did prove most of his programs, but used a higly idiosincratic language and style. Be advised that this is _hard_ going!